# How to make outlook addin msi package (using installshield) should install dotnet framework as well

Tags: installshield, setup-deployment

I have created the setup package for my outlook Addin using below link

[Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767(v=vs.120).aspx)

But i don't know how to make the same package should install or ask to install required dotnet framework (4.5.2).

Please guide me how to make setup should also dotnet framework to be installed.

Selecting prerequisite on **Application Data (Step 2) => Redistributables** also throwing error for setup.msi (no error for setup.exe but still .net framework not installed)

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What version of Installshield are you using?

Comment: Hi @SteinÅsmul, I am using "Installshield 2015 Limited Edition"